# PyCharm coffee filewatcher

Tags: django, coffeescript, pycharm

I got this directory structure (django project):

```html
-myproject
  +mysite
  -myapp
    -static
      -myapp
        -script
          -coffee
            +views
            +controllers
            +models
            app.coffee
          -js
            +views
            +controllers
            +models
  manage.py
```

How can i set coffeescript watcher to save *.js files in the same subdirectory of **js** directory. For example:

/coffee/app.coffee -> /js/app.js

/coffee/views/myview.coffee -> /js/views/myview.js

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960810/phpstorm-how-do-i-setup-less-to-output-to-css-directory-with-file-watcher), its essentially the same but you'll watch for CS changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i got the desired result by this macros:

```
$FileParentDir(coffee)$/js/$FileDirPathFromParent(coffee)$
```