# PhpStorm - Sass File Watcher - Output directory of compiled CSS

Tags: sass, phpstorm, file-watcher

Sorry in advance if I'm posting in to the wrong stack. I'm new to PhpStorm (coming from NetBeans) and I'm struggling to configure a File Watcher to compile my Sass files to the correct location.

The file I need compiling is located in

```
/sass/admin/styles/output/default.sass
```

I need it to compile the CSS to

```
/web/css/admin/styles/output/default.css
```

My arguments path for the watcher is

```
--no-cache --update $FileName$:$ContentRoot$/web/css/$FileRelativeDir$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

Which ends up compiling the file to

```
/web/css/sass/admin/styles/output/default.css
```

I need to remove the `sass` part from the `$FileRelativeDir$` macro but I don't know if this is possible. Is it possible to achieve this kind of file structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered here - 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15965088/1389760

I changed my argument path to

```
--no-cache --update $FileName$:$ContentRoot$/web/css/$FileDirPathFromParent(scss)$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

Changing the macro allowed me to set a parameter that removed the 'SCSS' from the directory path, and it now compiles to the desired location.