# PHPStorm IDE TypeScript File Watcher

Tags: typescript, filesystemwatcher, phpstorm

By default in PHPStorm 6 the compiled *.js are created in the same folder than the *.ts files.

What I need is that the compiled *.js and *.d.js be in a different subdirectory than the same of the *.ts files.

In resume:

- I have the root folder "Project"
- I have a subfolder "ts" which all *.ts files resides.
- I have a subfolder "scripts" where I want the compiled *.js and *.d.js be.

How can I accomplish this with PHPStorm TypeScript file watcher?

I've tried several macros like in the Output field at the File Watcher dialog like:

```
$FileParentDir$/scripts/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js:$FileParentDir$/scripts/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js.map
```

but none of them worked.

Comment: Should be similar to [LESS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15965088/104891) and [JADE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15505281/104891) file watchers configuration with the output in different subdirectories.

Comment: @CrazyCoder: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction but not solver my issue. For your help I voted both of your answers there :D Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @CrazyCoder's references I (finally!) managed to bring this to working fine.

The output file path you have to specify it in the `Arguments` parameter, not in the `Output` path's one.

The trick was that `--out` doesn't accept folder paths, instead you have to use the file path.

See image for reference of a fully functional configuration.

In this configuration the organization is:

- `ts/`: `*.ts` files.
- `scripts/`: compiled `*.js` & `*.js.map` & `*.d.ts` files.

[image]

**NOTE:** In newer versions of the compiler the correct parameter is `declaration` (without trailing `s`) and not `declarations`.

Comment: Great post!  FYI there is an error in the screenshot.  Should be: `--declaration` NOT `--declarations`  (singular not plural) if you want the .d.ts file

Comment: Thanks! :) You're partially right on the `declarations` being `declaration`. In older versions of the compiler was with the trailing `s`, but now in the newer versions is `declaration`. I updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 5):

The 'Output paths' field in File Watcher configuration just tells the IDE where to look for created files (used for auto-synchronization) and has no meaning for the program being run. TypeScript compiler has the --out  option that tells the compiler where to put the generated files

Please, try the following:

Arguments: --sourcemap $FileName$ --out $ProjectFileDir$/scripts/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js

Working directory: $FileDir$

Output Paths: $ProjectFileDir$/bin/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js:$ProjectFileDir$/bin/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js.map

Hope this helps