# Setup Jade With webstorm on MAC

Tags: macos, node.js, web, ide, pug

I am getting an error while compiling a jade file on my mac. I have already read too many blog posts but the problem still exits.

Here is a screenshot of the error I am getting:

[image: Setup Jade using webstorm Mac]

Can anyone tell me how i can setup jade in Webstrom MAC.

In terminal when i am trying to compile using this command i got error no: 156

```
mandeepgill-macpro:~ mandeepgill$ cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
mandeepgill-macpro:htdocs mandeepgill$ cd HTMLCodes
mandeepgill-macpro:HTMLCodes mandeepgill$ cd Sports
mandeepgill-macpro:Sports mandeepgill$ cd public_html
mandeepgill-macpro:public_html mandeepgill$ jade main.jade main.html



/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/bin/jade:156
              if (err) throw err;
                             ^
Error: EISDIR, open 'main.html'
mandeepgill-macpro:public_html mandeepgill$
```

Comment: Your screenshot is showing file watcher settings of WebStorm, not an error. Could you please post the exact command you used for compiling  using the command line?

Comment: Sorry but i don't know much about stack overflow editor so i added error in my last post.

Comment: But the problem is i want to setup File watcher for jade in Web storm

Answer (score 0):

The [EISDIR error is caused when a Node application expects a file, but gets a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417118/using-node-js-i-get-error-eisdir-read).

This particular instance of that error was thrown by [this block of code](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/a21a53609871db61875a69ea49c5712dc7aa8d85/bin/jade.js#L156):

```
fs.writeFile(path, output, function(err){
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('  \033[90mrendered \033[36m%s\033[0m', path);
        });
```

You can tell because it's not error number 156, but the line number of the relevant code.

Do you, by any chance have a directory named `main.html` in `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/HTMLCodes/Sports/public_html`?

Also, you should be able to just execute the command, `jade main.jade` without the second argument. That would seem to make your life easier.

Though if your dead set on using Webstorm on a Mac, [this configuration should work equally well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15505281/1168038), or to keep it really simple, just put `$FileName$` in arguments and get rid of the output paths.

This seems to have been a fairly common problem with Webstorm watchers though, so you might want to just use the command line `jade --watch`.